# Creating Firefox profile and switching off the marionette

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am coming from Ruby background, I know how to do this in Ruby Selenium Binding, but I don't know how to do it Java Selenium Binding,

I have this code to create Firefox profile

```
 FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(pathToProfile);
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

It works in selenium 2.53 but it's throws error in very recent selenium binding 3.11.0, Can anyone tell me what's the alternative?

And also I wanted to switch off the marionette to connect to Legacy Firefox driver, I can do this with the following code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

But if I use the above line, then it gives the FirefoxDriver is deprecated. Can anyone guide me how to create profile as well as how to switch off the marionette?

Comment: Let me know if you are open to consider other answers.

Comment: @DebanjanB Sure, Please go on!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes `FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities)`  is deprecated.

**Alternate** way would be to go with **options**:

```
FirefoxOptions foptions =  new FirefoxOptions(capabilities);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(foptions);
```

**Update** :  [**In order**]

```
FirefoxOptions foptions =  new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(pathToProfile);
foptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
foptions.setCapability("marionette", false);
foptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 52\\firefox.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(foptions);
```

Comment: how to pass the profile argument now? first question.

Comment: how to combine both? Need to pass the Firefox profile and foptions(your example variable)?

Comment: with options you and set the capabilities too !

Comment: Can you please order the lines?

Comment: in which order you want ?

Comment: Okay, give me a min, Let me understand this.

Comment: yeah sure ! go ahead !

Comment: Btw , I have rearranged this and combine both of them , hope it will be easy for you to understand !

Comment: Perfect, Can you please let me know how to add the binary path as well? `File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 52\\firefox.exe");`

Comment: you can use foptions.setBinary(path); as well !

Comment: Use this code : foptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox 52\\firefox.exe");

Comment: No problem mate ! and thanks for upvote and acceptance !

Answer (score 1):

To use an existing **Firefox Profile** for your *Test Execution* first you have to create a *Firefox Profile* manually following the instructions at [**`Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows`**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows). Now you have to pass the *Firefox Profile* to a *FirefoxOptions* class object. Additionally as you would be using the *Legacy Firefox Browser*
you have to set **marionatte** to **`false`** through a `DesiredCapabilities` class object which you need to `merge()` into the *FirefoxOptions* class object as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(testprofile);
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("marionatte", false);
options.merge(dc);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

---

### Update

I am not sure about your *usecase* and why you want to use **Legacy Firefox Driver**. But as per the *GitHub* discussion [**`Unable to Start Firefox Using the Legacy Driver on a 3.5.3 Grid`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4637) @jimevans clearly mentions :

> The legacy Firefox driver won't work with Firefox 53 or so. You might get the browser to launch, but the language bindings will be entirely unable to communicate with the driver (because Firefox will refuse to load the browser extension that is the legacy Firefox driver).

@barancev also mentions :

> A binding should not pass OSS capabilities in W3C-compliant parts of payload, in "capabilities" block. They are allowed in "desiredCapabilities" block only. Perhaps, Mozilla broke Selenium compatibility in Firefox 48 in release channel, but restored it in version 52 in esr channel. It was unexpected, but it's true.

It's all upto you to take a informed descission.

Comment: First line is not necessary,right? because we are using Legacy driver?

Comment: But If have to use Legacy driver, then first line is not necessary, eh?

Comment: @Rajagopalan _Legacy Driver_ will not require the first line but in absence of _GeckoDriver_ I am not sure if _Legacy Driver_ will be compatible with _Selenium 3.11.0_ and functions e.g. `merge()`. Update me the status please.

Comment: I have been using WATIR which is using recent Ruby Selenium Binding, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Won't comment on `watir`implementation. I have added an update with the comments from _Selenium Committers_ of the _Selenium Factory_. Keep me updated about the status.

Comment: You are right, selenium legacy driver wouldn't work from 48 version onwards, but ESR version of firefox still has the legacy driver inside. So switching is still possible.

Comment: You asked me why I go for legacy driver, this question is one of the example, Legacy runs fine but geckodriver wouldn't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186199/not-able-to-select-option-open-link-in-new-tab-in-right-click-using-selenium

Comment: @Rajagopalan I have been observing all of your comments/answers/questions of late. IMO, you are trying to walk down the lane too fast. Take your own time to go through the documentation and discussions on stackoverflow. If you have a question feel free to raise a ticket. But please don't jump the gun as in **Legacy runs fine but geckodriver wouldn't**. It's **counter productive** for the future readers.

Comment: I am not against geckodriver if it completely works like legacy driver but it's missing many of it's feature. I have raised a ticket as well for geckodriver problem, read here github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/960 ! I have explained you the main difference between implicit wait and explicit wait in your commnent, I hope you must have seen it.