# not able to select option open link in new tab in right click using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Summary : Link is not getting open in new tab.

Here is my code with the real url :-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("https://us.justdial.com/NY/New-York/Afghani-Restaurants/ct-16110200");
WebElement rightclickelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/section/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(rightclickelement);
action.contextClick(rightclickelement).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Expected : Link should get open in new tab.

Actual : Link gets open in current tab instead of new tab.

Comment: How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are many spelling mistake in your program, I corrected it. When I run your program, it runs as expected when I use legacy driver, but it's not running when I use geckodriver. If you are willing to proceed further with legacy firefox driver, I will give you the code.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : Thanks...
Please provide me the code....

Comment: Okay, I have written the answer below, you may have a look at that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First off, uninstall the existing Fire fox and delete the profile and then install the ESR version of Firefox, ESR version is must! To get the ESR version, simply type Firefox ESR in your google, that will pave the way for you to installation file.

Here is the code

```
        FirefoxOptions foptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        foptions.setCapability("marionette", false);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(foptions);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.navigate().to("https://us.justdial.com/NY/New-York/Afghani-Restaurants/ct-16110200");
        WebElement rightclickelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/section/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.contextClick(rightclickelement).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Comment: @Jyoti kayle can you accept my answer , there is a tic in the left top corner of my answer, you need to click that

Comment: @Jyoti kayle No, you still haven't done, If you have done, then then the tic will become green, Just look top left corner of this answer where you can see one tic, you need to click that and it would become green.

Comment: @Jyotikayle  No, you still haven't done, If you have done, then then the tic will become green, Just look top left corner of this answer where you can see one tic, you need to click that and it would become green

Comment: i have clicked and got the message "Thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Jyotikayle I am not asking you to cast vote, I am asking you to accept my answer, there is a tic below the down arrow(to downvote) where you need to click.

Comment: @Jyoti kayle I am not asking you to cast vote, I am asking you to accept my answer, there is a tic below the down arrow(to downvote) where you need to click, Once after it received your click, it will become green.

Comment: @Jyotikayle Kindly look at this answer of me where you can see green tic, can you see that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197699/filling-out-form-with-selenium-works-on-chrome-but-not-firefox

Comment: @Jyoti kayle there is no green colour tic, when you press that tic, it become green.

Comment: Please don't get wrong, and check it again, i took someone help to do so, i did't aware with That.....

Comment: @Jyoti kayle Okay, no problem. Do you want an answer to your second question ?

Comment: Yes....  Here is the next query/Question, that i have already asked but did't get working answer, please have a look :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199983/not-able-to-read-mobile-number-from-a-webpage/50203025?noredirect=1#comment87474195_50203025

Comment: @Jyotikayle sure!

Comment: @Jyotikayle Another guy gave a answer which works for me, you just check out again clearly, you might have missed out.

Comment: @Rajagopalan fwiw, as of Firefox 59 & Geckodriver 0.20, context clicking works just fine.

Comment: @titusfortner I am not saying it's not clicking I am saying it would not open the tab, it opens in the same window, Is it opening an another tab for you?

Comment: Another answer still suggesting the unmaintained, unsupported, to-be-removed **Legacy Firefox Driver**. This is definitely a bad answer and needs to be avoided at all cost.