# Filling out form with Selenium works on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to fill out a textarea using Selenium and ruby in Firefox, but for some reason, the code below doesn't work. When I switch the same script to Chrome driver though, it does work.

```
browser.textarea(:placeholder => "Add a comment…").set "#{randomly_chosen_comment}"
```

On firefox, I get this error:

```
/Users/miajohansson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:623:in `raise_present': element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextArea: located: true; {:placeholder=>"Add a comment…", :tag_name=>"textarea"}> to be present (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from /Users/miajohansson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:669:in `rescue in element_call'
    from /Users/miajohansson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:680:in `element_call'
    from /Users/miajohansson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/user_editable.rb:11:in `set'
    from instabot.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from instabot.rb:36:in `each'
    from instabot.rb:36:in `block in <main>'
    from instabot.rb:35:in `loop'
    from instabot.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

I've been working on this for many hours and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I need to get it to work on Firefox. Any help is very appreciated!!

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the url? Let me check it?

Comment: Kindly provide the html because problem seems to be interesting.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I added the html code and the link is just any Instagram post

Comment: Oh sorry url is inside the program, I can see.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try now.

Comment: Actually I have forgotten my password for instagram, Do one thing, I will give you the code which connects to the legacy driver rather than geckodriver, I believe it would work.  what do you say?

Comment: @Rajagopalan I haven't heard of the legacy driver, but I can try it. You don't need to be signed in though to go to the url. For example, just click: https://www.instagram.com/p/BiZ9W8OAGCg/?taken-by=sincerelyjules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue; it is working for me without using the deprecated driver. Are you using the latest Firefox & geckodriver version?

One issue is that the dots are not periods, but different unicode; this will work with the latest geckodriver just fine:

```
browser.textarea(placeholder: /Add a comment/).set "#{randomly_chosen_comment}"
```

Or, because that is the first `textarea` on the page, you can just do:

```
browser.textarea.set "foo"
```

Comment: I have written this answer for Java binding where I was asking her to use Legacy Driver, can you please take this question and can you achieve through geckodriver? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186199/not-able-to-select-option-open-link-in-new-tab-in-right-click-using-selenium/50190327?noredirect=1#comment87454594_50190327

Comment: Hi can you use your geckodriver to the above condition? If you
 can't, can you admit with usage of geckodriver is useless?

Comment: Yes, I just said it worked for me in irb with latest production Firefox and driver, and that I couldn't reproduce OP issue.

Comment: No, I am not asking to work for this question instead i am asking you to find the solution for the given below url , I have written an answer in Java binding where I was asking to use Legacy Driver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186199/not-able-to-select-option-open-link-in-new-tab-in-right-click-using-selenium/50190327?noredirect=1#comment87454594_50190327

Comment: This thread is for this question. For this question, there is no need for legacy, so don't tell OP to use an explicitly deprecated tool when they don't need to use it.

Comment: Oh okay, so when he faces that problem ,I need to ask him to move to legacy driver? Why struggling with the problematic driver rather than using super duper driver which works perfectly for everything.

Comment: As of today Geckodriver is better than Legacy driver at the things the vast majority of people do in their tests, and bugs as defined by the w3c specification are getting fixed. Legacy driver goes away entirely very soon: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/10/03/legacy-add-on-support-on-firefox-esr/

Comment: Did you see that people quickly fix their errors as soon as I guide them to use Legacy Driver ?

Comment: I want to tell you about this new WATIR, it's taking 2 to 3 seconds to select a select list, this is extremely slow compared to the earlier version but you released as performance improvement, I don't understand why. It select one select_list and then it takes 3 seconds before it selects another one. Extremely slow compared to all the version which come before it.

Comment: @Rajagopalan this is not the place to discuss it. Open an issue on github and I'll take a look before we release it.

Comment: sure, i will do it tomorrow, and i have replied about `b.table.rows` in github, did you see it?