# Not Able to read mobile number from a webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to read the mobile no. from a webpage, please help
Here is the my code :

```
public void g()
{     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\cchauhan\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.justdial.com/Ahmedabad/Knife-Fork-Restaurant-Shah-E-Alam-Tollnaka-Opposite-Swaminarayan-College-Shah-Alam/079PXX79-XX79-170524174654-D3J2_BZDET?xid=QWhtZWRhYmFkIEFmZ2hhbmkgUmVzdGF1cmFudHM=");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String mobile =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comp-contact']/span[2]/a[1]/span[4]")).getText();
    System.out.println(mobile);
}
```

Comment: You mean the phone numbers starting with `+91`? Those can't be extracted from the HTML source code or DOM as each number is an image placed there via css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get the phone number

```
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.justdial.com/Ahmedabad/Knife-Fork-Restaurant-Shah-E-Alam-Tollnaka-Opposite-Swaminarayan-College-Shah-Alam/079PXX79-XX79-170524174654-D3J2_BZDET?xid=QWhtZWRhYmFkIEFmZ2hhbmkgUmVzdGF1cmFudHM=");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String mobile =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'businfo seoshow')]/span/p[3]")).getText();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{10},\\d{10}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mobile);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but still above code is not able to read the mobile no.. it is printing blank space.

Comment: Have you use the same xpath?

Comment: I am able to get the phone number from the above code.

Comment: i have used exact same code that you have written and also used same xpath, but it did't work for me

Comment: Really Strange.