# How to load a existing FirefoxProfile through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

First time posting here, so I address a problem I cannot solve.Checked Stackoverflow and google. There's some answers for java which I couldn't decode. Therefore you might mention that this is a duplicate, but so far no one answered such a question.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary 
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\MozillaFirefox\firefox.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\dxcwavid.Zydrius5')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, firefox_binary = binary)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

geckodriver: 0.23.0

python: 3.7.1

selenium: 3.141.0

Windows: 10 1511

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files (x86)\MozillaFirefox\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\Users\User\Documents\dxcwavid.Zydrius5")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: SyntaxError '(Unicodeescape)'  code can't decode bytes in position 2-3: Truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: try following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935424/10413416

Comment: That's why I put 'r' before string (r'C:\Program Files (x86)\MozillaFirefox\firefox.exe'). Besides the code runs perfectly this cannot be some syntax problem, instead I miss something or must be somewhere in Geckodrive...

Answer (score 0):

To load an *existing* **Firefox Profile** through *Selenium* and *Python* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\moskcpdq.SeleniumTest')
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page Title is : Google
  ```
- References:

  - [webdriver.FirefoxProfile(): Is it possible to use a profile without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356081/webdriver-firefoxprofile-is-it-possible-to-use-a-profile-without-making-a-cop/49358656#49358656)
  - [Creating Firefox profile and switching off the marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171476/creating-firefox-profile-and-switching-off-the-marionette/50172383#50172383)

Comment: @ZydrunasAgniauskas Of-coarse it works at my end flawless. Can you update the question with your latest code trials and error stacktrace for further analysis?

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver`

`myprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Profile\dxcwavid.Zydrius5')`
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=myprofile, executable_path=r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Profile\geckodriver.exe')`
`driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')`
`print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)`

Then I added to favorite, open again and nothing is marked as favorite.
Cannot provide any errors as it doesn't produce any :)
Also my firefox version 64.0 (32-bit)

Comment: Here's geckodrive.log file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GhB5niKfYpjGm-IvXs867IWvtw8M6dmt

Comment: by which I understand that doesn't even bothering about my profile :)

Comment: @ZydrunasAgniauskas Go through the link **Creating a new Firefox profile on Windows** within the second _Reference_ discussion within this answer. How did `dxcwavid.Zydrius5` land up in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Profile`?

Comment: I put everything in one place as well as geckodrive so the code would be easier to read, apologies to not inform you

Comment: Also I did create the Profile as you in the link